# Windows 8 store app with c# and socket.io client

Tags: c#, node.js, windows-8, socket.io, windows-store-apps

I want to connect my Windows 8 store app with a node.js socket.io server. Is there any library for c# and socket.io?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Not really. Right now I'm searching for a library which is for .Net 4.5 and not only .Net 4.0. http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/ for example is great but it has no support for .Net 4.5 and Windows 8 Store Apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a hidden browser element with socket.io javascript client in it.
It can function as the proxy between nodejs server and your win8 app.

Comment: how is this possible?? im stuck on this now myself a pointer to anything would be brilliant

Comment: wow.. this is a really old topic. I dont do windows developement anymore but the idea was that you have a browser component that loads for example http://www.yoursite.com/socketio.html which relays the message forth and back to the client.